# Apache Axis fails after change in WSDL

Tags: java, soap, coldfusion, wsdl, apache-axis

I have a SOAP web service served from a .net app. Sometimes we add to some of the object definitions but these are always optional and from a XML/HTTP standpoint the xml tags that represent those fields could be left out and it works fine. This should let existing users of the web services keep working.

and this is exactly how it does work for almost everyone. Clients using .net, python, ruby etc all have no problem with this. But any change at all seems to break anyone using Apache Axis2 in Java.

It seems that on every request Axis checkes the endpoints WSDL and verifies that it is EXACTLY like the stubs it has. If not then it throws an exception. (unexpected subelement)

Is there any option in Axis to turn this feature off and have Axis just assume it's current stubs are correct?

UPDATE:
I should also note that this is a problem for clients using ColdFusion since it uses Axis2

Comment: Switching to CXF is not an option for my project, and I need to Axis fetching the WSDL before every request.  Any more ideas?

Comment: I have found my problem, and it wasn't with Axis.  The WS I am calling is for a PHP app called Magento, and it requests it's own WSDL when processing a request.  I was misinterpreting the log messages as Axis making the request.  My bad.  Hopefully this comment will save someone from spending as long as I did trying to diagnose this.  I mean, why would you fetch your own WSDL on every SOAP request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm kind of remote debugging this from our clients perspective. I Got everything up and running and was able to reproduce the error with an older version of Axis2 (1.2). The newest version I have (1.5.4) does not seem to have this problem (using ADB bindings) So upgrading is a good workaround for our clients using Axis straight up. Unfortunately a number of our clients are using ColdFusion which has the older version built in so I'll have to figure out what to do about them.

Answer (score 1):

With Apache CXF, by default, it would also likely throw an exception due to an element it doesn't understand.  However, you can set a property of "set-jaxb-validation-event-handler"  to "false"
on the endpoint and it would be ignored.

Comment: I'm starting to think we should just change our example code to use something else and advise our clients against Axis. CXF may work. Thanks for the tip.